# I want to link up my blade files with master blade layout but it is not working

Tags: html, laravel

In my master layout i have a dashboard i want to click a link and that link will direct me to views where i created index.blade.php file

I have tried like this

```
<li>                          
    <a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\Portal\resources\views\Group\index.blade.php">
        <i class="fas fa-table"></i>Groups
    </a>
</li>`enter code here`
```

Comment: As in you want to redirect to that page or you want to include that page in your master layout?

Comment: Please provide more details. What kind of unexpected/unwanted result your current code (reproduced in the question) produces?